# Is there anyway to repent for proselytizing for idol worship?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

In hilchos teshuva of the Rambam (4:1), he states that one for proselytizes for idol worship is unable to repent. Are there any other sources that comment on anyway to repent for such a sin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Rambam doesn't say that such a person is unable to repent, just that Hashem won't provide him an opportunity like He does for most people (אין מספיקין בידו לעשות תשובה). In halacha 6 there, the Rambam clearly states that neither this nor anything else prevents (מונעין) teshuvah, just impedes it (מעכבין).

Comment: See the guide for more info.

Comment: According to Rambam does it make a difference if the person was doing it as a former Frum person or if he didn't know any better?

Comment: @larry909 Elsewhere (Hilchos Mamrim 3:3) the Rambam speaks of תינוקות שנשבו, people who were raised in a non-Torah observant environment, who are not held fully responsible for their transgressions, since they didn't know better. Presumably the same thing would apply here, but given that we're anyway talking about something that Hashem  (rather than an earthly beis din) would or wouldn't do, then it would be up to His judgment.

Answer (score 4):

Coming from a more reformed opinion, I think Hashem would have no issues with your repentance. It says in [Yechezkel 18:21-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.18.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> And if the wicked man repent of all his sins that he has committed and
>   keeps all My laws and executes justice and righteousness, he shall
>   surely live, he shall not die. All his transgressions that he has
>   committed shall not be remembered regarding him: through his
>   righteousness that he has done he shall live. Do I desire the death of
>   the wicked? says the Lord God. Is it not rather in his repenting of
>   his ways that he may live?

Comment: Great to have you learning with us, @Rivka! I hope you don't mind that I added a link to the text you cited.

Comment: Thank you so much!